# Перемещение fixed блока с ограничением

Tags: css

Страница поделена на 2 части.
В правой части  с `position: fixed;`
Соответственно при прокручивание страницы, фиксированный блок движется за нами. НО! мне необходимо, чтобы он доходил до конца контента и не выезжал на футер.

```
<div>
    <div>
        content
    <table>
        <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>fixed</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    <div>
        footer
    </div>
</div>
```

скриншоты прилагаются
[image: скрин 1]

выехала

[image: скрин 2]

```css
body {
  background: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}
A img {
  border: none;
}
A {
  color: blue;
  Text-decoration: none;
}
A:visited {
  color: blue;
  Text-decoration: none;
}
A:active {
  color: blue;
  Text-decoration: none;
}
A:hover {
  color: blue;
  Text-decoration: none;
}
div.all_body {
  width: 100%;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 auto;
}
div.main_menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  text-align: center;
  background: white;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.main_table_content .user_panel {
  position: fixed;
  text-align: center;
}
.user_panel .img_panel {
  width: 150px;
  height: 210px;
  align: center;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
  margin: 20px;
}
.username_panel {
  font: 1.1em Segoe Print, sans-serif;
}
div.content {
  background: #eff4ff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 auto;
  width: 93em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 15px;
}
.main_table_content {
  width: 100%;
}
.main_table_content td {
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
.main_table_content p {
  margin: 10px;
}
.content_table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
.top_girls_table {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
div.info_about {
  height: 500px;
  background: #f6b98d;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
div.info_blog {
  height: 500px;
  background: #71c0ac;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
div.info_rating {
  height: 500px;
  background: #93c9d6;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
div.info_chek {
  height: 500px;
  background: #d6b2e9;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
div.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background: #b2c7e9;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Наточка</title>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="all_body">
    <!-- Главное меню -->
    <div class="main_menu">

    </div>
    <!-- Главное меню конец -->

    <!-- Контент -->
    <div class="content">

      <table class="main_table_content">
        <tr>
          <td width="*">

          </td>

          <td width="15%" style="border-left: 1px solid black;">

            <!-- Панель пользователя -->

            <div class="user_panel">
              fixed
            </div>

          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
    <!-- Контент конец -->



    <div class="footer">
      <table width="100%" height="300px">
        <td width="20%" style="background:#d7cfcf;">
          <!-- связь -->

        </td>
        <td width="*">
          <!-- баннеры рекламы -->

        </td>
        <td width="20%" style="background:#7979b7;">
          <!-- деньги -->

        </td>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Приложите css стили, а лучше сделайте рабочий fiddle пример. Без этого ваша проблема не ясна.

Comment: Насколько я знаю, придётся писать JS

Comment: что бы написать css не нужно писать  js

Comment: добавил html, css коряво немного, но суть ясна вроде...

Comment: absolute + stycky + firefox :)

Comment: не могли бы поподробней? и при чем тут мозила?